# How to split string using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string contains multi language text as follow

```
{|en|}Audio Albums{|/en|}{|ar|}الألبومات الصوتية{|/ar|}
```

I need a function to get the text of specific language

```
getText("en") should returns Audio Albums
```

I think I have to use regular expression.

Comment: This sounds more like you want a better String format and use a corresponding parser. For example csv (or dsv) or JSON etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Unfortunately, I must working with this format because it comes form API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\{\|"+lang+"\\|\\}(.*)\\{\\|/"+lang+"\|\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : null;
```

Comment: I tried \\{\\|ar\\|\\}(.*?)\\{\\|/ar\\|\\} regular expression and it returns null

Comment: use the `find` method instead

Comment: Added .* at the beginning and end. find() however should work too..., thanks Casimir.

Comment: Adding `.*` is a bad idea and will generate a lot of backtracking for nothing. see the number of steps with and without: https://regex101.com/r/qF6dC8/1

Comment: @Casimir you are right I used find function instead and it worked, I don't need to use .* at the beginning and end